# Gradle does not works correctly in FreeBSD Jail

Tags: java, gradle, jail

Here is my problem.

First, I use FreeBSD as my development platform for Java application, everything works when I start Gradle outside of Jail, but when I start Gradle in the Jail, the Gradle show message like "Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details"

```
root@java: gradle init
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status 
for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status 
for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status 
for details
```

and when I use "gradle --status" to check what happened"

```
root@java: gradle --status
 PID  STATUS   INFO
 3921 UNKNOWN  UNKNOWN
 3918 UNKNOWN  UNKNOWN
 3922 UNKNOWN  UNKNOWN
```

This only happens when I start Gradle in FreeBSD Jail. So what is the problem?

Updated 03-12-2018

I reinstall the Jail which used to be the Java development and I enable **allow.mount** for the jail according to the OpenJDK installation guide, but the Gradle still does not work correctly, so the problem is not related to the mount in the jail.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time to find the solution, I think I have got the best solution for this problem by myself. First and also the most important to anyone who is new to FreeBSD,

**DO NOT USE EZJAIL AND DO NOT SETUP JAIL BY YOURSELF**.

After I choose use **iocage**, a tool used to manage jails, all problems are gone. And I also found that setup ipv6 correctly for system and jails is very important. A lot of services and tools use ipv6 as a channel to communicate with the system.

Gradle and the Clojure development tool -- CIDER are the two tools which only works when the ipv6 setting of the system and jail are correct.

If you have the same problem as mine, I wish this will help you.